# Unable to run the batch file for phoronix-test-suite in WindowsXP

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, php, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to install phoronix-test-suite in my windows-XP, 64bit.   According to the user manual, I only need to run a .bat file from respective directory.

When I double click on the .bat file or try to run it from CMD (need php to run it...), I am getting a pop-up[open with] prompting me to choose the program I want to open this file with...

I can open with note pad.. wordpad... whatever.. but I simply couldn't run the file!!!

I am using the desktop as an administrator and have all privilege...
Can anybody tell me why is this happening??!!

Regards...

Comment: Are you sure it supports Windows XP? XP is long past its end of life. I can't find any specific list of supported Windows OS's, though.

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear "need php to run it.."

You can also look at http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads

### **Software Requirements**

The only mandatory requirement for the Phoronix Test Suite on Linux, Solaris, *BSD, Hurd, and Mac OS X operating systems **is PHP CLI (packages for it are generally called php5-cli or php-cli or just php)**. Only PHP 5.3 or greater is needed and not a web server or other packages commonly associated with PHP. As an alternative to PHP, the Facebook HHVM (HipHop Virtual Machine) interpreter is also supported for running the Phoronix Test Suite.

Based on the above and error message it seems you didn't install PHP

Comment: Actually, I have made sure that PHP is installed. That was my first step...  to check the dependencies...